# Cambiar tamaño o estilo de botones Java

Tags: java, java-swing, java-ee, botón, java-8

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo Java y estoy poniendo en practica los conocimientos adquiridos con un programa simple. Estoy teniendo un problema al cambiar el tamaño de los botones, y no se si seria posible cambiarle el estilo a los botones asi como en html con codigo css se puede modificar por completo el boton.

**Codigo:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class FrameEleccion extends JFrame{

public FrameEleccion(){

    setTitle("Eleccion");
    setBounds(500,500,400,400);

    add(PanelEleccion, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    PanelEleccion.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,1,10));

    PanelEleccion.add(boton1);
    PanelEleccion.add(boton2);
    PanelEleccion.add(boton3);
    PanelEleccion.add(boton4);

    EventoEleccion eventoBotones=new EventoEleccion(this);

    boton1.addActionListener(eventoBotones);
    boton2.addActionListener(eventoBotones);
    boton3.addActionListener(eventoBotones);
    boton4.addActionListener(eventoBotones);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

}

class EventoEleccion implements ActionListener{

    private FrameEleccion eleccion;

    public EventoEleccion(FrameEleccion eleccion) {

        this.eleccion = eleccion;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();

        if (boton1 == source  ){

            FrameEntrada frameEntrada=new FrameEntrada();
            eleccion.dispose();

        }else if (boton2 == source ){

            FrameSalida frameSalida=new FrameSalida();
            eleccion.dispose();

        }else if (boton3 == source ){

            FrameAnadirDatos frameAnadirDatos=new FrameAnadirDatos();
            eleccion.dispose();

        }else if (boton4 == source){

            eleccion.dispose();

        }

    }


}

private JPanel PanelEleccion=new JPanel();
private JButton boton1=new JButton("Entrada");
private JButton boton2=new JButton("Salida");
private JButton boton3=new JButton("Añadir datos");
private JButton boton4=new JButton("Cerrar");

}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

El tamaño de los componentes, en este caso de los botones, tiene más que ver con el tipo de Layout que establezcas.

> Tu le has establecido este layout `setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,1,10))` a tu panel...

```
PanelEleccion.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,1,10));
```

El cual hace que aparezca cada uno de los botones en una sola fila '*ocupen todo el ancho de cada una de las filas*'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He creado otro panel a tu código, y lo he añadido a la parte central del marco, estableciéndole otro layout. Al cual le he añadido un par de botones.

```
private JPanel panelCentral = new JPanel();
private JButton botonPrueba = new JButton("Prueba");
private JButton botonPrueba2 = new JButton("Prueba2");

add(panelCentral, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panelCentral.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Y ahora para poder cambiar el tamaño del botón '**botonPrueba2**', le establezco un tamaño mínimo, un tamaño máximo y un tamaño *preferido*, que será el que *establezca* siempre que pueda.

```
botonPrueba2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
botonPrueba2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150,60));
botonPrueba2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));
panelCentral.add(botonPrueba2);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el estilo de los botones facilmente.

```
  button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  Border line = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK);
  Border margin = new EmptyBorder(5, 15, 5, 15);
  Border compound = new CompoundBorder(line, margin);
  button.setBorder(compound);
```

Estos son algunos de los atributos que puedes modificar, te paso un link para que puedas ver todas las demas - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJButtonLookandFeel.htm

Comment: No me funciona como quiero me hace un marco pero no me modifica el boton